# How to call .net API from another .net API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, .net-core

Is that possible to call an API from an existing API in .net? If yes, How we can call?

Comment: You can use the `HttpClient` class.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Perfect! It might work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For performing `Http` calls you should use the `HttpClient` located in the `System.Net.Http`  namespace.

For more info:
`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2`

I have included an example for doing a `Post` request:

**POST**

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MyObject
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int ID{get;set;}
}
public async Task PerformPostAsync(MyObject obj)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client=new HttpClient();
        string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(str, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await this.client.PostAsync("http://[myhost]:[myport]/[mypath]",
                               content);

        string resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //deserialize your response using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resp)
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //treat your exception here ...
        //Console.WriteLine("Threw in client" + ex.Message);
        //throw;
    }

}
public static async Task Main(){
    MyObject myObject=new MyObject{ID=1,Name="name"};
    await PerformPostAsync(myObject);

}
```

Comment: Perfect! Am able to call one API from another API but am receiving null object in my destination API. What could be the reason?

Comment: It is most probably a mapping issue.Ensure that the `serialized object` is `deserialized` correctly before calling your other `api`.And after that be sure to use same type of object on the `other` side.

Comment: just i missed "/"(Slash) at the end. Thats why i was getting null. Now its done and Upvoted! Thank you!

Comment: I'm using role/claim based authentication with JWT token in my base API. Is there a way to login and get authenticated with a secondary API that calls the base API?